# Windows Server mysql system tables converted to innodb won't start

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows-server-2008

We recently ran a script against a mysql to convert all tables to use innodb.  Unfortunately, this also included the system tables.  The server will no longer start.

I didn't figure it would probably matter in this case, but also tried the 
innodb_force_recovery in the config file and restarting.  Same error.

Is there any way to get back to myisam from this dumb conversion on the system tables?

```
Dump we're receiving

Thread pointer: 0x92eb40
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
000000014009A9A1    mysqld.exe!ha_resolve_by_name()[handler.cc:135]
0000000140119F6F    mysqld.exe!open_binary_frm()[table.cc:897]
000000014011C12B    mysqld.exe!open_table_def()[table.cc:644]
0000000140078204    mysqld.exe!get_table_share()[sql_base.cc:379]
000000014007829D    mysqld.exe!get_table_share_with_create()[sql_base.cc:478]
000000014007A9B3    mysqld.exe!open_unireg_entry()[sql_base.cc:3874]
000000014007E0C1    mysqld.exe!open_table()[sql_base.cc:2931]
000000014007ED61    mysqld.exe!open_tables()[sql_base.cc:4630]
000000014007F258    mysqld.exe!open_and_lock_tables_derived()[sql_base.cc:5041]
000000014003643C    mysqld.exe!plugin_load()[sql_plugin.cc:1417]
000000014003772A    mysqld.exe!plugin_init()[sql_plugin.cc:1252]
000000014001DB5E    mysqld.exe!init_server_components()[mysqld.cc:4021]
000000014001E315    mysqld.exe!win_main()[mysqld.cc:4490]
000000014001E6AF    mysqld.exe!mysql_service()[mysqld.cc:4666]
00000001402EBAB7    mysqld.exe!_callthreadstart()[thread.c:295]
00000001402EBB85    mysqld.exe!_threadstart()[thread.c:275]
0000000076C7A4BD    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
0000000077076461    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0000000000000000): =
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that is bad news.  The `mysql` tables should *not* be converted from MyISAM; MySQL cannot work if they are.

Plan A:  If you have any sort of dump, reload at least the database `mysql` from that dump.  Then we can discuss how to get *your* tables loaded or whatever.

Plan B:  Install a new copy of MySQL; it will have 'correct' in `mysql` (but won't have your `GRANTs`, etc.)  Then we can discuss how (and whether) you can get *your* tables reloaded/rebuilt.

What dump(s) do you have?  Recent?  Old?  In MyISAM?  In InnoDB?  What was the value of `innodb_file_per_table`?  What version are you coming from / going to?  (There, I am thinking about "transportable tablespaces".)

Won't help at the moment, but you should review the other gotchas in the conversion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb .